# How to unassign shortcut keys without knowing what it maps to

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to unassign a shortcut key if you do not know what the name of the command that it maps to is?

For example, I want to use the Resharper Inspect Hierarchy shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>. However when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> then I get a list of recently edited files. Can I find what is assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> without having to trawl through every item in `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard`?

**Edit:** Just to be clear - I know that `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard` has the Remove button. I just need help finding which command to remove from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution, so I'll share it for anyone else who has the same problem.

Go to `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard`. Try to assign the shortcut key that you want to an arbitrary command, and VS will tell you what it currently conflicts with. Then you can go to that command and unassign it.

[image: Doing a lookup on the short cut key]